# How to remove the header of a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I downloaded the following presentation template online.

[image]

How I can remove the part circled in red?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the template?

Comment: you need to select beamer theme, which hasn't such header. See its documentation, section *16 Inner Themes, Outer Themes, and Templates*  where are listed many themes.

Comment: Or not load any theme. An empty preamble is a good start. The best paintings always begin with a blank canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove this part by redefining the headline template:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
```